# Intuitive explanation of Newton - Pepys problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Pepys_problem) for description of problem:

> In 1693 Samuel Pepys and Isaac Newton corresponded over a problem
> posed by Pepys in relation to a wager he planned to make. The problem
> was:
>
> Which of the following three propositions has the greatest chance of success?
>
> 1. Six fair dice are tossed independently and at least one “6” appears.
> 2. Twelve fair dice are tossed independently and at least two “6”s appear.
> 3. Eighteen fair dice are tossed independently and at least three “6”s appear.
>
> Pepys initially thought that outcome C had the highest probability,
> but Newton correctly concluded that outcome A actually has the highest
> probability.

**I know how A has highest probability mathematically.** But it feels kind of unintuitive to me.

Newton's explanation [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Pepys_problem#Newton%27s_explanation)

> Although Newton correctly calculated the odds of each bet, he provided
> a separate intuitive explanation to Pepys. He imagined that B and C
> toss their dice in groups of six, and said that A was most favorable
> because it required a 6 in only one toss, while B and C required a 6
> in each of their tosses. **This explanation assumes that a group does
> not produce more than one 6, so it does not actually correspond to the
> original problem**

**So my question is what is the intuition behind the result?**

Comment: The respective probabilities are approximately .67, .62 and .60--very nearly the same. So it may not be easy to get a compelling intuitive argument. Getting more than one 6 in a group is relatively unlikely, and the error cuts similarly across the three cases, so Newton's explanation may hint in a useful direction. (As if Newton needs any help from me.)

Comment: This is a tricky question.  Here's one way to use Newton's idea: split the 12 throws into two sets of 6 and write $P(n)$ for the probability of $n$ 6s in 6 throws. $P(B)\leq P(A)$ is $P(0)P(\geq 2)+P(1)P(\geq 1)+P(\geq 2) \leq P(\geq 1)$, which is the same as $2P(1)+P(0) \geq 1$. So $A$ being more likely than $B$ depends on the fact that 0 or 1 sixes are relatively likely.

Answer (score 1):

**Generalising the question**

Let $X \sim Bin(\frac{n}{p},p)$, so $\mu = n$

Does $\mathbb{P}(X \ge n)$ increase or decrease with $n$?

If $\mathbb{P}(X \ge n)$ is decreasing with $n$, then Proposition 1 is more likely than 2 is more likely than 3, and vice versa.

**Intuition**

1. $\mathbb{P}(X = \mu) > 0  \therefore \mathbb{P}(X < \mu) + \mathbb{P}(X > \mu) < 1$
2. In fact, $\mathbb{P}(X < \mu) < \frac{1}{2}$ and  $\mathbb{P}(X > \mu) < \frac{1}{2}$.

Think of this as some probability being used by $\mathbb{P}(X = \mu)$, and the remaining probability being shared roughly equally between $\mathbb{P}(X > \mu)$ and $\mathbb{P}(X < \mu)$.

3. As $n$ becomes large, $\mathbb{P}(X = \mu) \approx 0$ and $\mathbb{P}(X < \mu) \approx \mathbb{P}(X > \mu) \approx \frac{1}{2}$.

As n increases, think of $\mathbb{P}(X < \mu)$ and $\mathbb{P}(X > \mu)$ consuming the probability occupied by $\mathbb{P}(X = \mu)$.

In particular, $\mathbb{P}(X < \mu)$ is growing with $n$.

Equivalently, $\mathbb{P}(X \ge n)$ is decreasing with $n$.

**Summary**

$X \sim Bin(6n,\frac{1}{6})$

For $n=1$, $\mathbb{P}(X=n)$ is large enough that both $\mathbb{P}(X < n) < \frac{1}{2}$ and $\mathbb{P}(X > n) < \frac{1}{2}$.

As $n$ increases, $\mathbb{P}(X < n)$ increases strictly, converging to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Therefore, $\mathbb{P}(X \ge n)$ decreases strictly $w.r.t.n$.

Therefore, $\mathbb{P}(\ge 1$ six out of 6 dice) > $\mathbb{P}(\ge 2$ sixes out of 12 dice) > ...

Comment: If $X\sim Bin(n,p)$ then for a fixed $\mu$ we don't have that $P(X=\mu)$ is decreasing. For instance for $p=1/6, \mu = 1$ and $n=4,5,6,7$ we get respectively the probabilities $0.39\ldots,0.40\ldots,0.40\ldots,0.39\ldots$. What's true is that for $n$ large enough we would get that it is decreasing; but in OP, why does it make intuitive sense that the jump into "large enough" $n$ has already occurred? Moreover, you take varying rather than constant $\mu$ which even further complicates the situation.

Comment: @Snaw I think you need to read my answer more carefully, because I said X ~ Bin(n/p, p). I did not say X ~ Bin(n,p).  Also, mu specifically denotes the expected value of X, which is equal to n.

Comment: I did notice that, but what I tried explaining is that your conclusions are not obvious. The problem is, you say that as $n$ becomes large, $P(X=\mu)$ tends to $0$, which is true; but then you seem to imply that this means that $P(X=\mu)$ is decreasing for all $n$. If I understand you correctly then the rest of your explanation relies on this. How do you show this without any calculation? What is your intuition for this? Let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: Let ${n \choose k} := \mathbb{P}($roll n dice and get exactly k sixes$)$. 

Let the 'ratio of the numbers' ('RON') refer to $\frac{n}{k}$.

Intuitively (for me), if we preserve the 'RON', we maintain a form of symmetry as we increase $n$, and so probabilities converge smoothly towards their limiting values.

Although @Snaw correctly shows that ${4 \choose 1} > {5 \choose 1} > {6 \choose 1} > ...$ does not hold, this is not relevant because this sequence did not preserve the 'RON'.

In particular, for Pepys' question to Newton, the 'ratio of the numbers' = $\frac{1}{6}$ is conserved.

Comment: Pepys' question preserves the ratio of numbers by increasing k proportionally with n (i.e. 1 out of 6, 2 out of 12, etc.) This means the intuition that probabilities move strictly towards their limiting values is correct. Of course, if I prove intuition via calculation this defeats the point of giving an intuitive answer.